# Detect whether a process is being debugged; in kernel land

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, driver

Is there a way to detect (in kernel-mode) that a debugger (in user-mode) is attached to another process (also in user-mode) on Windows ?

I cannot find any API or flag in the `EPROCESS` structure that would reveal this information. Ideally, I'm looking for a flag that cannot be altered from a program in user-mode, nonetheless I'm unaware if this information is also kept at kernel level.

Thanks !

Comment: `NTSYSAPI BOOLEAN NTAPI PsIsProcessBeingDebugged (PEPROCESS Process)`

Comment: Hey @RbMm, many thanks for your answer! I googled for `PsIsProcessBeingDebugged` and I cannot find anything from Microsoft's website. I bet this is an undocumented API? If so, feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: yes, this is undocumented api, but very simply - https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Ps/pshelper.c#L129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exist (from xp) undocumented api

```
extern "C"
NTKERNELAPI
BOOLEAN
PsIsProcessBeingDebugged(PEPROCESS Process);
```

which `return Process->DebugPort != NULL` very simply and reliable api, can be used at any irql (because Process object in not paged memory).

- **Library:** *NtosKrnl.lib*
- **IRQL:** *Any level*